# Validate multiple html forms on the same page

Tags: php, html

I want to validate two forms on one .php page in my manual account activation system.

I have two forms:

1. Accept form
2. Decline form

And when you enter a username and click the button on one of these forms, it runs PHP code to change the value in the MySQL column. Fortunately I have the code, but the problem is, that when both forms are validated on the same page with `method="POST" the account` is activated instead of being rejected.

I know that you're gonna say that this is impractical and other stuff but welp that's what I am comfortable with.

I tried doing `action="different_page.php"` and there just do `require("original_page.php")` and just do `if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {`  but it did not work. Same with different `POST=""` values.

Any ideas?

Snippet of the code that is on one page:

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    
    $usrname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_DELETE['usrname']);
    $reason = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_DELETE['reason']);
$sql = "DELETE * FROM admin WHERE username = '$usrname'";
$getemail = "SELECT email FROM admin WHERE username='$usrname'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $getemail);


if(mysqli_query($db, $sql)){
    $error = "Account declined.";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result)) {
    $to      = $row['email']; 
    $subject = 'subject'; 
    
    $message = '
    some email text
    
    '; // Our message above including the link
    
    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From:no-reply@mywebsite.com' . "\r\n"; // Set from headers
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); // Send our email

  }
  
    }
}



if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

$usrname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['usrname']);
$sql = "UPDATE admin SET active = '1' WHERE username = '$usrname'";
$getemail = "SELECT email FROM admin WHERE username='$usrname'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $getemail);



if(mysqli_query($db, $sql)){
$error = "Account activated.";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result)) {
$to      = $row['email']; 
$subject = 'account activated blah blah'; 

$message = '
meow
'; // Our message above including the link

$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .= 'From:no-reply@mywebsite.com' . "\r\n"; // Set from headers
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); // Send our email
}
} else {
    $error = mysqli_error($db);
}
}
```

and the forms are:

```
 <form method="POST">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="usrname">
            <input type="submit" name="activate" value="Activate"><br>
            
            <?php echo $error; ?>

    </form><br>
    <br>
    <form method="DELETE">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="usrname">
         
            <input type="submit" name="decline" value="Decline"><br>
            <?php echo $declineerror; ?>

    </form><br>
```

Comment: You should add some POST parameter that tells the server what the request form data should be used for(don't try shortcuts, do this explicitly). It could be f.ex an `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete" />`. Or perhaps using the existing submit buttons and check for decline or activate in $_POST.

Comment: in second form, you can use post method. so why you are using their DELETE method

Comment: Depending on how you're doing this, checking `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` might be a good thing as well. (Previous comment assumed both forms were POST. Sorry, I didn't look close enough.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

> Change the second form method `DELETE` to POST.

GET & POST are the only valid HTTP method values for the method attribute. See the [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attr-fs-method) for more information.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['activate'])) 
{    
    echo "activate button clicked";
}

else if(isset($_POST['decline']))
{
    echo "decline button clicked";
}

?>
```

**HTML Form**

```
 <form method="POST" name="activate">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="usrname">
            <input type="submit" name="activate" value="Activate"><br>
            
            <!-- <?php echo $error; ?> -->

    </form><br>
    <br>
    <form method="POST" name="decline">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="usrname">
         
            <input type="submit" name="decline" value="Decline"><br>
            <!-- <?php echo $declineerror; ?> -->

    </form><br>
```